# Wordpress - WooCommerce - How to hide virtual products from a specific user role

Tags: woocommerce

I'd like to hide all virtual products (and virtual variations) based on a specific user role.

I thought to use an approach like this... but these products are not kept in specific categories, they are populated throughout the entire store.

```
function hide_products( $q ) {

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( in_array( 'dealer', $current_user->roles ) ) {

        $q->set( 'tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => '123',
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        ) ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'hide_products' );
```

Any ideas how I could accomplish this? Thanks for your help!